# UILabel does not update with data from CoreData on willDisplayCell.

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITabController that has 4 tabs. On one of the tabs I have a uitableviewcontroller that hosts cells that contain a UILabel (this UILabel is named 'dataCount) that will display the number of items in an entity found on core data and a UILabel that simply displays a name (this UILabel is named 'nameLabel'). I attempted to, whenever the tab is displayed, search through core data for an attribute with the same name as the cells **nameLabel**, once found I simply use some business logic to fetch data from core data and then insert the number of items I find in the **dataCount** UILabel. This works, but what doesn't work is having this data updated constantly on the UITableViewCell whenever the tab is visited. Can anyone show me how I can consistently get data from core data and display it on a UILabel found on a cell whenever that particular tab is visited? Something that did work, but isn't feasable, is reloading the tableview on willDisplayCell. Doing this simply increases the CPU consistently.

**My Attempt:**

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



        // Search for number of notes
        var notesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Notes")
        var numberOfNotes = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(notesFetchRequest, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject]
        var notesCount = 0

        if let notes = numberOfNotes {
            for items in notes as! [Notes] {
                if items.name == (cell as! MyCell).nameLabel.text!{
                    notesCount += 1
                }
            }
        }


        (cell as! MyCell).dataCount.text = String(notesCount)


        //self.mytableview.reloadData() -- works but CPU increases exponentially

    }
```

Comment: Not sure how you have your project set up. But I would reload the tableView when I detected a press on the relevent tab. Maybe use "didSelectViewController" from the UITabController delegate method.

Comment: Another thing to add, you do not want to reload the tableView in "willDisplayCell". It will just create a never ending loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I reload the tableview on **viewDidAppear** the data is correctly displayed and updated. Problem solved. If anyone has any other recommendations in terms of optimization and feasibility please let me know.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.mytableview.reloadData()
    }
```